# Yii2 custom component not recognizing getter or setter properties?

Tags: object, properties, yii2, components

I have a custom component that handles the application options.

For some reason, when I access the method like so:

```
Yii::$app->option->user('setting_name');
```

I get the following error:

```
Calling unknown method: app\models\Option::user()
```

Here is a partial snippet of the class:

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;

class Option extends Component
{

    public function getUser($key)
    {

        $options = self::getAllOptions('user');
        return $options[$key];

    }

    public function setUser($key, $value)
    {

        $return = self::getAllOptions('user', true);
        $model = $return['model'];
        $options = $return['options'];
        // update the specific option
        $options[$key] = $value;
        self::setAllOptions('user', $options, $model);

    }

}
```

And here is the component registration in the application configuration:

```
...
'components' => [
    'option' => [
        'class' => 'app\models\Option',
    ],
],
...
```

Why isn't it recognizing the property using the getter and setter methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply use :

```
Yii::$app->option->getUser('setting_name');
```

Your `getUser()` and `setUser()` functions are not getter/setter functions since a getter doesn't have any arguments, and a setter has only one argument.

Even if it was a valid getter, you simply cannot use it like this, properties defined by getters can be used like class variables, not functions !

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-properties.html

Comment: That is how I currently access the properties.  I was trying to refactor a little bit.  I have read that article 4 times over the last day, and can't decifer where I am going wrong.  Why are they not proper a Getter/Setter?